# How to insert youtube link in Civimail, like in mailchimp?

Tags: civimail

I am trying to send a newsletter with a youtube video link. How to insert youtube link in Civimail, like in mailchimp?

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and paste the link into the body of the template.

You can embed it in html so that it opens inside the message - youtube provides "embed" code to do that. When you paste this in, click the "source" button and paste it there before saving.

Hope this helps,

John